# The size of the grid varies between groups of a ggplot2 heatmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

Hello I have the dataset below:

```
gene_symbol<-c("DADA","SDAASD","SADDSD","SDADD","ASDAD","XCVXCVX","EQWESDA","DASDADS","SDASDASD","DADADASD","sdaadfd","DFSD","SADADDAD","SADDADADA","DADSADSASDWQ","SDADASDAD","ASD","DSADD")
panel<-c("growth","growth","growth","growth","big","big","big","small","small","small","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDA<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDb<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf1<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf2<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf3<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf4<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf5<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDA1<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDb1<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf1<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf11<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf21<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf31<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf41<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
ASDDAf51<-c("normal","over","low","over","normal","over","low","over","normal","over","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF","DF")
Gene_states22<-data.frame(gene_symbol,panel,ASDDA,ASDDb,ASDDAf,ASDDAf1,ASDDAf2,ASDDAf3,ASDDAf4,ASDDAf5,ASDDA1,ASDDb1,ASDDAf1,ASDDAf11,ASDDAf21,ASDDAf31,ASDDAf41,ASDDAf51)
```

Then I create a ggplot2 heatmap with groups with:

```
 library(plotly)
library(ggplot2); library(reshape2)
g <- melt(Gene_states22, id.vars = c("gene_symbol","panel"))
p1<-ggplot(g, aes(gene_symbol,variable)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = value),
                                                     colour = "grey50") + scale_fill_manual(values=c("white", "red", "blue","black","yellow","green","brown"))+
  facet_grid(~panel,switch = "x", scales = "free_x")+
  labs(title = "Heatmap",x = "gene_symbol",y="sample",fill="value")+
  theme(title = element_text(family = "sans serif", 
                             size = 14, 
                             face = "bold"), 
        axis.title = element_text(family = "sans serif", 
                                  size = 16, 
                                  face = "bold", 
                                  color = "black"), 
        axis.text = element_text(family = "sans serif", 
                                 size = 11),
        axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 5, b = 0, l = 5)),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey50"),
        panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"),
        strip.placement = "outside")
p1
```

and then I convert it to plotly with:

```
 ggplotly(p1)%>%
  layout( autosize = F, width = 1350, height = 600,hoverlabel = list(bgcolor = "white",
                                                                     font = list(family = "sans serif", 
                                                                                 size = 9, 
                                                                                 color = "black")))
```

The size of the grid varies between groups - this should be kept constant.

Comment: your code is not working as it is. There is at least one typo and I am getting this: `Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 7 needed but only 3 provided.`.

Comment: I editted. Try now plz

Comment: I re editted with some fixes

Comment: For some reason nrow=1 does not work with facet_grid so I removed it.

Comment: You have free scales, so the scales (and thus breaks and thus grid lines) are going to vary..

Comment: Yes that fixes it.